# How to Identify Special Charecters in a NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsjsonserialization, nsrange

Have a small question how to identify special charecter's in a strring like {} * & ^ % $ # @ ! _ . Nsrange is not helping me out.

Here is my issue i have a json array

```
enter code here{contacts:[{name:xyz,phone:123},{name:abc,phone:123},{name:{},phone:{}}]}
```

Here comes my problem last object in that json gives me {},which makes my tableview throw me a sigbart.How can i skip this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MaxGabriel that this isnt *your* specific problem :)

---

BUT on to the answer to the question:

test if for invalid chars:

```
[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]
rangeOfCharacterFromSet == YES if the array contains a char from the set
```

to rm them all:

```
id s = @"$bla++$bleb+$blub-$b";
NSCharacterSet *ch = [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:ch] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@",ch, s);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't that the character is invalid. The {} is an empty dictionary in the JSON. You should check for the case where the dictionary is empty and not pass it to your tableview-controller.

Comment: doesnt answer the question IMHO :)